# Действие происходит столько раз, сколько и записей в базе данных

Tags: python, sqlite

Код

```
        conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/vkbot/db.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        rows = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(user_id)).fetchall()
        rows_admin = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM admin").fetchall()
        if not rows:
            cursor.execute(
                "INSERT INTO users VALUES ({}, 2500, 'пользователь', null, null, null, null, null, null, null)".format(
                    user_id))
            conn.commit()
        count = cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT() FROM users").fetchone()
        elif text[0].lower() == 'код':
            for row_admin in rows_admin:
                for row in rows:
                    if len(text) == 1:
                        api.messages.send(peer_id=peer_id,
                                          message=head + ',\n\n |» Используйте → код [код]' + footer)
                    elif row[9] == 'used':
                        api.messages.send(peer_id=peer_id,
                                          message=head + ',\n\n❌ |» Вы уже использовали промокод' + footer)
                    elif text[1] != row_admin[0] or row_admin[2] == 0:
                        api.messages.send(peer_id=peer_id,
                                          message=head + ',\n\n❌ |» Неверный промокод' + footer)
                    else:
                        cursor.execute(
                            "UPDATE admin SET use = {} - 1 WHERE promocode = '{}'".format(row_admin[2], text[1]))
                        cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET promocode = 'used' WHERE id = {}".format(user_id))
                        cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET balance = {} + {} WHERE id = {}".format(row[1], row_admin[1], user_id))
                        conn.commit()
                        conn.close()
                        api.messages.send(peer_id=peer_id,
                                          message=head + ',\n\n |» Вы активировали промокод и получили сумму в размере ' + str(row_admin[1]) + '$' + footer)
```

Проблема в том, что если в базе 2 записи, то он отправляет все сообщения которые находятся в `elif text[0].lower() == 'код':` 2 раза, нужно чтобы он отправлял 1 раз, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите понять, почему python код выводит много строк, то:

По вашему запросу сложно понять, где именно содержится 2 записи, но суть в том, что у вас есть 2 цикла, которые собственно говоря и выводят все строки, вместо одной

```
elif text[0].lower() == 'код':
    for row_admin in rows_admin:  # <---- 1й цикл
        for row in rows:  # <---- 2й цикл
```

Если вам надо показать только 1 запись для админа, поменяйте 1й цикл на

```
row_admin=rows_admin[0]  # Или на row_admin=rows_admin[-1]
```

в зависимости от того, какую запись надо получить.

Если надо показать 1 запись, то поменяйте 2й цикл на подобное:

```
row=rows[0]  # Или на row=rows[-1]
```

опять-таки в зависимости от того, какая запись нужна.

А вообще лучше сделать это через `SQL`.
Просто то, что вам надо получить только в одном экземпляре, то добавьте в `select` параметр `limit 1`. Он заставит sqlite вернуть только 1 запись(первую), независимо от того, сколько их в таблице.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы действия не повторялись

Comment: @АминАлиев А что именно не понятно в ответе, как убрать повторение? Я же написал в ответе все варианты.